# Composite Control has design time error in Certain Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a solution in ASP.Net 2008 (C#) with:
- A Project with a Composite control (with some buttons and textboxes).
- Another project (application) just to test the control.

I started to test the control inside a page or webform. It had some design time errors
so when I dragged the control to the page it showed the "Error Rendering Control" in design time. I corrected the errors, rebuild the project with the control, 
and the control appears fine in design time.

But I added another webform, I dragged the control on it, and the "Error Rendering Control"
appears again. I added another webforms and drag the control on them and that error appears too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, because I have a lot of code in my composite control, I didn't noticed that I had a .FindControl sentence inside my composite control. I put that senrtence just for testing, but I forgot to delete it from my code.
So the page when it worked fine had the control specified in FindControl, the other pages
had not.